# How to put data from a custom dialog into a specific range in the sheet without using appendRow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having trouble putting data from a custom dialog into a specific range in the sheet, like this:
[image]
[image]

Everytime i enter new data in the dialog, it should append a new row in that particular range.
So far i'm using appendRow for that matter but the problem with that is that appendRow counts in ALL columns in the sheet, so that i'm having blank cells in the particular range, like this:
[image]

This is one of the codes i'm using :

```js
//STUNDE EINTRAGEN VIA START
function showDialogKBSTART() {

  gotoSheetSchueler();

  var widget = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("formKBSTART.html").setHeight(450).setWidth(450);
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(widget, "Stunde eintragen");
}

function appendRowFromFormSubmitKBSTART(formKBSTART) {
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
    .appendRow([formKBSTART.Datum, formKBSTART.Inhalt, formKBSTART.Sozialform, formKBSTART.Dauer, formKBSTART.Lehrkraft,, formKBSTART.Ausfall]);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('KlassenbuchGesamt')
    .appendRow([SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName(), formKBSTART.Datum, formKBSTART.Inhalt, formKBSTART.Sozialform, formKBSTART.Dauer, formKBSTART.Lehrkraft, formKBSTART.Ausfall]);

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("A9:A").setNumberFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("A9:F").sort({column: 1, ascending: false});

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('KlassenbuchGesamt').getRange("B2:B").setNumberFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('KlassenbuchGesamt').getRange("A2:G").sort({column: 2, ascending: false});

      Utilities.sleep(500);

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Stunde eingetragen!","",3);

      Utilities.sleep(500);
  
  hide();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script>
    function submitForm() {
      google.script.run.appendRowFromFormSubmitKBSTART(document.getElementById("KBstart"));
      document.getElementById("form").style.display = "none";
      
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
  <div id="form">
  
  <form id="KBstart">

    <label for="Datum"><b>Datum</b></label></br>
    <input type="date" id="Datum" name="Datum"><br><br>

    <label for="Inhalt"><b>Inhalt</b></label></br>
    <input type="text" id="Inhalt" name="Inhalt" size="60"><br><br>

    <label for="Sozialform"><b>Einzel oder Gruppe?</b></label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Ez" name="Sozialform" value="Ez">
        <label for="Ez">Einzel</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Gr" name="Sozialform" value="Gr">
        <label for="Gr">Gruppe</label><br><br>

    <label for="Dauer"><b>Dauer</b></label></br>
       <select id="Dauer" name="Dauer">
          <option value="45">45</option>
          <option value="60">60</option>
          <option value="90">90</option>        
        </select>
    
    <div>
    </br>  

    <label for="Lehrkraft"><b>Lehrkraft</b></label></br>
      <select id="Lehrkraft" name="Lehrkraft">
          <option value="Alexander Michaelis">Alexander Michaelis</option>
          <option value="Thomas Weider">Thomas Weider</option>
          <option value="Merve Besser">Merve Besser</option>        
        </select>
    
    <div>
    </br>  

      <label for="Ausfall"><b>Ausfall?</b></label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="yes" name="Ausfall" value="E">
        <label for="yes">Entschuldigt</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="no" name="Ausfall" value="UE">
        <label for="no">Unentschuldigt</label><br><br>

      
      <input type="button" value="Eintragen" onclick="submitForm();google.script.host.close()">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <button type="reset" value="Reset">Neu</button>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me with getting the data in the specific range and appending a new row without using appendRow? Thanks!

UPDATE!!:
The following code was suggested:

```js
function appendRowFromFormSubmitKBSTART(formKBSTART) {


var kb = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('KlassenbuchGesamt');


var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var col = 0; // column A
// get the number of last empty row in column 'A'
var col_data = sh.getDataRange().getValues().map(x=>x[0]);
var last_row = col_data.length - col_data.reverse().findIndex(x=>x!='') + 1;

// get the range
var myRange = sh.getRange('A' + last_row + ':F' + last_row);

// data
var myData = [
    formKBSTART.Datum,
    formKBSTART.Inhalt,
    formKBSTART.Sozialform,
    formKBSTART.Dauer,
    formKBSTART.Lehrkraft,
    formKBSTART.Ausfall
];

// set the data into the range
myRange.setValues(myData);

ss.getRange("A9:A").setNumberFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
ss.getRange("A9:F").sort({column: 1, ascending: false});

kb.appendRow([SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName(), formKBSTART.Datum, formKBSTART.Inhalt, formKBSTART.Sozialform, formKBSTART.Dauer, formKBSTART.Lehrkraft, formKBSTART.Ausfall]);
kb.getRange("B2:B").setNumberFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
kb.getRange("A2:G").sort({column: 2, ascending: false});

ss.toast("Stunde eingetragen!","",3);

hide();


}
```

UPDATE2:
Here is the code in its simplest form:

```js
function showDialogKBSTART() {

  var widget = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("formKBSTART.html").setHeight(450).setWidth(450);
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(widget, "Stunde eintragen");
}




function appendRowFromFormSubmitKBSTART(formKBSTART) {


var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var col = 0; // column A
// get the number of last empty row in column 'A'
var col_data = sh.getDataRange().getValues().map(x=>x[0]);
var last_row = col_data.length - col_data.reverse().findIndex(x=>x!='') + 1;

// get the range
var myRange = sh.getRange('A' + last_row + ':F' + last_row);

// data
var myData = [
    formKBSTART.Datum,
    formKBSTART.Inhalt,
    formKBSTART.Sozialform,
    formKBSTART.Dauer,
    formKBSTART.Lehrkraft,
    formKBSTART.Ausfall
];

// set the data into the range
myRange.setValues(myData);



}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script>
    function submitForm() {
      google.script.run.appendRowFromFormSubmitKBSTART(document.getElementById("KBstart"));
      document.getElementById("form").style.display = "none";
      
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
  <div id="form">
  
  <form id="KBstart">

    <label for="Datum"><b>Datum</b></label></br>
    <input type="date" id="Datum" name="Datum"><br><br>

    <label for="Inhalt"><b>Inhalt</b></label></br>
    <input type="text" id="Inhalt" name="Inhalt" size="60"><br><br>

    <label for="Sozialform"><b>Einzel oder Gruppe?</b></label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Ez" name="Sozialform" value="Ez">
        <label for="Ez">Einzel</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Gr" name="Sozialform" value="Gr">
        <label for="Gr">Gruppe</label><br><br>

    <label for="Dauer"><b>Dauer</b></label></br>
       <select id="Dauer" name="Dauer">
          <option value="45">45</option>
          <option value="60">60</option>
          <option value="90">90</option>        
        </select>
    
    <div>
    </br>  

    <label for="Lehrkraft"><b>Lehrkraft</b></label></br>
      <select id="Lehrkraft" name="Lehrkraft">
          <option value="Alexander Michaelis">Alexander Michaelis</option>
          <option value="Thomas Weider">Thomas Weider</option>
          <option value="Merve Besser">Merve Besser</option>        
        </select>
    
    <div>
    </br>  

      <label for="Ausfall"><b>Ausfall?</b></label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="yes" name="Ausfall" value="E">
        <label for="yes">Entschuldigt</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="no" name="Ausfall" value="UE">
        <label for="no">Unentschuldigt</label><br><br>

      
      <input type="button" value="Eintragen" onclick="submitForm();google.script.host.close()">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <button type="reset" value="Reset">Neu</button>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

So basically its this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you need `range.setValues()` method. Something like this:

```
var myRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A9:F9');

var myData = [
    formKBSTART.Datum,
    formKBSTART.Inhalt,
    formKBSTART.Sozialform,
    formKBSTART.Dauer,
    formKBSTART.Lehrkraft,
    formKBSTART.Ausfall
];

myRange.setValues([myData]); // <--- square brackets!
```

Of course you need to calculate the destination range every time. First it can be `A9:F9` then it will be `A10:F10`, etc.

You can find the first empty cell at the end of a column this way:

```
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var col = 0; // column A
var col_data = sh.getDataRange().getValues().map(x=>x[col]);
var last_row = col_data.length - col_data.reverse().findIndex(x=>x!='')+1;
```

Thus the part of the code could look like this:

```
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

// get the number of first empty row at the end of column 'A'
var col_data = sh.getDataRange().getValues().map(x=>x[0]);
var last_row = col_data.length - col_data.reverse().findIndex(x=>x!='') + 1;

// get the range
var myRange = sh.getRange('A' + last_row + ':F' + last_row);

// data
var myData = [
    formKBSTART.Datum,
    formKBSTART.Inhalt,
    formKBSTART.Sozialform,
    formKBSTART.Dauer,
    formKBSTART.Lehrkraft,
    formKBSTART.Ausfall
];

// set the data into the range
myRange.setValues([myData]); // <---- square brackets!
```

---

Another approach: you can remove the empty cells every time (and move the data up) in particular ranges. I think it's a less efficient approach, though.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I updated my code with your help (see original post)

But i'm getting an error message: "Exception: Range not found" in line 183 
`var myRange = ss.getRange('A'+col+':F'+col+'9');  // get the range`

Comment: Sorry it was a typo in my sample. It should be `last_row` instead of `col`: `var myRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A'+last_row+':F'+last_row);` and without `'+9'`

Comment: I'm still getting the same error unfortunately

Comment: Update the code in your question. I need to see exactly how it looks like now.

Comment: I already had added the new code in my question  :)

Comment: I've updated my answer, try it. But your updated code still contains the wrong `col` variable. You're trying to get the range 'A0:F0', it gets you the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240100/discussion-between-axis9011-and-yuri-khristich).

Comment: Hi! I'v updated the code in my question like you suggested, but i don't understand what you mean by "your updated code still contains the wrong col variable. You're trying to get the range 'A0:F0', it gets you the error."

Right now i'm getting the followeing error message with the updated code:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Datum' of undefined ("formKBSTART.Datum,")
l
so something has been changed, but i still dont know whats wrong

Comment: The error tells me that you're trying to run the function: `appendRowFromFormSubmitKBSTART(formKBSTART)` directly and this way you're getting the empty object `formKBSTART`

I suppose you should run the function `showDialogKBSTART()` instead

Comment: I was running the function `showDialogKBSTART()` , it's still not working, when i run the script, nothing happens, the dialog just closes. 
I added the suggested code in its simplest form to the bottom of my original post, maybe you can try it yourself?

Comment: Yes. I've found one more bug. It should be: `myRange.setValues([myData]);` -- in square brackets! Now it works.

Comment: `appendRows()` takes an [array], but `setValues()` takes [[2D array]]. Even if there is just one line or one cell. And, probably you don't need the line `var col = 0;` since you don't use the variable `col`.

Comment: OMG Thank you so much!!! it works perfectly !